# Web story about aliens who twist humans into various sub-humans

Tags: story-identification, aliens, genetic-engineering

It was hosted on its own page and was written much like a documentary about the rise and fall of the human race from the perspective of an alien narrator. There were plenty of illustrations to show the various creatures and 'sub-humans'.

Humans advanced and eventually colonized Mars (and other planets) in our system but because the cost of sending things between Earth and Mars was so expensive there was a lot of tension between them. Martian humans evolved to be lanky.

Eventually there were aliens that came by that gene spliced and mutated a lot of humans and dropped them off on various alien planets to study them and such. The story had chapters detailing each of these 'strains' of sub humans (each with an illustration) and how they either died off or regained their humanity (whatever was left of it anyways) and rejoined the galactic civilizations.

One such batch were turned into nothing but mindless pleasure pets that couldn't fathom anything bad. Another group was melded together like an amorphous blob and had to learn to rely on each other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you are thinking of "[All Tomorrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Tomorrows)" by Nemo Ramjet.

> Beginning in the near future, All Tomorrows chronicles the imagined entire future history of humanity over the course of the next several hundred million years. Over the course of the book, humanity experiences several triumphs and failures and diverges into several different distinct forms through evolution and genetic engineering.
>
> Following the colonization of Mars, a quick but catastrophic civil war between Earth and Mars and a large-scale colonization initiative carried out by genetically-engineered humans through the galaxy, All Tomorrows introduces a malevolent and superior alien race known as the "Qu", whose religion motivate them to remake the universe through genetic engineering.
>
> Following a brief war in which humanity is quickly defeated by the Qu, the aliens bioengineer the surviving humans as punishment, creating several different strange forms, many of them unintelligent, which are left to evolve on their own as the Qu leave the galaxy. Bioengineered forms of human created by the Qu range from worm-like humans and semi-sentient reptile-like forms to insect-eaters and strange modular and cell-based species.

Comment: Can you explain why this matches?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE, Beach Boy Fantastic. Please have a look at the help center for [guidelines on creating good answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).