# Residents of invaded planet turned into living sewage system

Tags: story-identification, books

I heard about this species from a book where a planet was invaded and the people ended up being turned into living sewage systems; they were cubed and couldn't move. I don't know the book but I was wondering what it was.

Comment: Interesting premise. I've fixed your tags. You may want to check [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) of prompts to elicit more details. Did you read this book yourself? When did you read or hear of it? Online? On paper?

Comment: Everyone got turned into toilets?

Comment: Oh, this is one of those books where the invaders are super-skilled at gene engineering and turn all the conquered races into various _things_...

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199180/web-story-about-aliens-who-twist-humans-into-various-sub-humans

Answer (score 25):

If it's an online book (published as a PDF) it might be [*All Tomorrows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Tomorrows) (2006) by C.M. Kosemen (under the pen name Nemo Ramjet).

[image: Cover of "All Tomorrows" showing 3 different evolved forms of humanity]

It details the future of humanity as it spreads through the galaxy, adapting to various planets by genetic engineering, until humanity meets the alien Qu.  The Qu conquer humanity, and remake it into various random things as punishment for resisting them.

About the "living sewage systems," the page for "Colonials" says:

> The Qu, with their twisted sense of justice, wanted to make them pay.
> Even extinction would be too light a punishment for resisting the star
> gods. The humans of the rogue world needed a sentence that would
> remind them of their humiliation for generations to come.
>
> So they were made into disembodied cultures of skin and muscle,
> connected by a skimpy network of the most basic nerves. They were
> employed as living filtering devices, subsisting on the waste products
> of Qu civilization like mats of cancer cells. And just to witness and
> suffer their wretched fate, their eyes, together with their
> consciousness, were retained.
>
> For forty million years they suffered; generation after generation were
> born into the most miserable of lives while absorbing the pain of all
> that they were going through.
>
> <sub>*All Tomorrows*, p. 36 "Colonials"</sub>

(Forty million years being the length of the dominance of the Qu before they moved on to other worlds to subjugate and remake.)

The accompanying picture of the remade Colonials certainly fits with your description of "cubed":

[image: Page 37, showing a field tiled with rectangular Colonials with randomly-appearing eyes and mouths]

You can read a copy of the e-book at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/book-all-tomorrows_202109/page/36/mode/2up).